# Reconstructing ContourPlot with ListContourPlot

Tags: plotting, implementation-details, function-comparison

Let `f` be some numeric function with two arguments

```
f[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := x y
```

For the purposes of this question `f` has a very simple form, but the function I am actually working with takes several seconds to evaluate. Therefore, I want to store every evaluation of `f`. This could be done with a memory function (`memf[x_,y_]:=memf[x,y]=f[x,y]`), but here I use `Sow` instead, i.e.

```
sowf[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := (Sow[{x, y, f[x, y]}, "f"]; f[x, y])
```

Now create a `ContourPlot` of `sowf` with

```
{plot, {{fPts}, {monitorPts}}} = Reap[
   ContourPlot[
     sowf[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1},
     EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x, y, f[x, y]}, "monitor"],
     PlotTheme -> "Monochrome",
     PlotPoints -> 3,
     MaxRecursion -> 0
   ],
   {"f", "monitor"}
];
```

The plot is now stored in `plot`, while `fPts` contains all results of evaluations of `sowf` and `monitorPts` contains all points that where sent to `EvaluationMonitor`.

Remark: I thought those two sets of points should be the same, but in fact `sowf` was evaluated one more time than `EvaluationMonitor` suggests:

```
Length /@ {fPts, monitorPts}
(* {10, 9} *)

Complement[fPts, monitorPts]
(* {{0.0005, 0.0005, 2.5*10^-7}} *)
```

The computation above will be done with the expensive `f` on a computer cluster, and I want to make some adjustments to the plot style and other options later on, without having to re-evaluate `f`.

My question is, how can I use either set of points to reconstruct the `ContourPlot`, using a `ListContourPlot`? Simply providing `ListContourPlot` with one of those sets results in a different plot:

```
contours = Sort@Cases[plot, Tooltip[__, n_] :> n, \[Infinity]]
(* {0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9} *)

Show[{
  plot,
  ListContourPlot[monitorPts, 
   ContourStyle -> Directive[Thick, Cyan, Dashed], 
   ColorFunction -> (Transparent &), Contours -> contours]
}]
```

[image]

```
Show[{
  plot,
  ListContourPlot[fPts, 
   ContourStyle -> Directive[Thick, Cyan, Dashed], 
   ColorFunction -> (Transparent &), Contours -> contours]
}]
```

[image]

Note, that `ListContourPlot` does not show all the contours I specified! The contours for 0.9, 0.8, and 0.7 are missing.

```
Tally@Cases[%, Tooltip[__, n_] :> n, \[Infinity]]
(* {{0.9, 1}, {0.8, 1}, {0.7, 1}, {0.6, 2}, {0.5, 2}, {0.4, 2}, {0.3, 2},
{0.2, 2}, {0.1, 2}} *)
```

What additional information does `ContourPlot` use?

When the number of points is large enough it works fine

```
{plot, {{fPts}, {monitorPts}}} = Reap[
   ContourPlot[
    sowf[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1},
    EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x, y, f[x, y]}, "monitor"],
    PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"
    ],
   {"f", "monitor"}
   ];
Show[{
  plot,
  ListContourPlot[fPts, 
   ContourStyle -> Directive[Thick, Cyan, Dashed], 
   ColorFunction -> (Transparent &)]
}]
```

[image]

but the actual `f` is, as I mentioned before, very expensive to evaluate, so I want to keep the number of plot points relatively low.

Comment: Which *Mathematica* version do you use? With versions 11.1.1 and 11.2.0 I get all the contours. But versions 8.0.4 and 10.4.1 do not generate contours for `0.9`, `0.8`, and `0.7`.

Comment: Interesting. I use 11.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

[Partial Answer - Please add your own answers as well!]

I cannot really explain why `ListContourPlot` and `ContourPlot` give different results, but there is a workaround using only `ContourPlot`.

We can create the plot as before

```
{plot, {fPts}} = Reap[
   ContourPlot[
    sowf[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1},
    PlotTheme -> "Monochrome",
    PlotPoints -> 3,
    MaxRecursion -> 0
   ]
];
```

and then define a memory-function

```
ClearAll[memf];
Do[memf[p[[1]], p[[2]]] = p[[3]], {p, fPts}];
```

to be used by `ContourPlot` with exactly the same settings for `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion` as before.

This requires, however, some amount of faith in Wolfram not changing anything in the `ContourPlot` routine from one MMA version to the next.

Comment: In addition: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5287817/590388

Answer (score 0):

Probably, `ContourPlot` and `ListContourPlot` use different `Method`s for the same set of function points.  See, for instance, the first answer to [question 69448](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t07KZ.png).  Not having the patience to experiment with these many possibilities, I suggest building an `Interpolation` function from `monitorPts`, and plot it with `ContourPlot`.

```
int = Interpolation[intpts = {Most@#, Last@#} & /@ monitorPts, 
    InterpolationOrder -> 2];
Show[{plot, ContourPlot[int[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 3, 
    MaxRecursion -> 0, ContourStyle -> Directive[Thick, Cyan, Dashed], 
    ColorFunction -> (Transparent &), Contours -> contours], ImageSize -> Large}]
```

[image]

`InterpolationOrder -> 2` can be omitted for larger values of `PlotPoints`.